# How to make activeTIntColor and activebackgroundColor of drawerItem work in react navigation 6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I was not able to change the activeTintColor and activeBackgroundColor of drawerItem in react-navigation 6, Eventhough I'm using those props on drawer item I can't see any changes in activeItem tintColor change in selected Item.Below here is the code that I'm using where I used the prop activeTintColor to set the active DrawerItem tint color but I don't see any changes in color and even I can't see which is active tab I'm on but navigation works fine.I am able to navigate to DrawerItem screens only thing it active Item which is selected doesn't seems applying activeTintColor etc

```
function DrawerNavigation() {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
            drawerContent={(nav) => {
                const { navigation } = nav;
                let state = navigation.getState();
                return (
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 100,
                                    borderColor: "black",
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderRadius: 50,
                                    marginVertical: 10,
                                    overflow: "hidden"
                                }}
                            >
                                <Image
                                    source={{
                                        uri: "https://m.cricbuzz.com/a/img/v1/192x192/i1/c170661/virat-kohli.jpg"
                                    }}
                                    resizeMode="cover"
                                    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <DrawerItem
                                label="Home"
                                pressColor="red"
                                icon={() => (
                                    <Image
                                        source={require("../assets/home.png")}
                                        style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }}
                                    />
                                )}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
                                activeTintColor="red"
                            />
                            <DrawerItem
                                label="Profile"
                                pressColor="red"
                                icon={() => (
                                    <Image
                                        source={require("../assets/profile.png")}
                                        style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }}
                                    />
                                )}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile")}
                                activeTintColor="red"
                            />
                            <DrawerItem
                                label="Cart"
                                pressColor="red"
                                icon={() => (
                                    <Image
                                        source={require("../assets/cart.png")}
                                        style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }}
                                    />
                                )}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Cart")}
                                activeTintColor="red"
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                );
            }}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={StackNavigation} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was facing a similar issue cause i be working with react-navigator 6.x but read the 5.x doc. To set the activeTintColor to all my screens i finnaly do it like that:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      drawerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "grey",
        width: "100%",
      },
      drawerActiveTintColor: "white",
      drawerInactiveTintColor: "yellow",
    }}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="One"
      component={OneStackScreen}
      options={{
        title: "One",
        drawerIcon: () => (
          <MaterialIcons name="home" size={24} color="white" />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Two"
      component={TwoStackScreen}
      options={{
        title: "Ma page",
      }}
    />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
            <View style={Styles.DrawerHeader}>
                <View style={Styles.ProfileImg}>
                    {userPic ? (
                        <Image
                            source={{
                                uri: userPic
                            }}
                            resizeMode="cover"
                            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <Image
                            source={{
                                uri: "https://m.cricbuzz.com/a/img/v1/192x192/i1/c170661/virat-kohli.jpg"
                            }}
                            resizeMode="cover"
                            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                        />
                    )}
                </View>
                <Text style={Styles.ProfileText}>{user}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.Divider}></View>
            {state.routes.map((route) => {
                return (
                    <DrawerItem
                        key={route.key}
                        icon={({ focused }) => (
                            <Icon name={listItemIcon} size={20} color={focused ? Colors.Primary : "black"} />
                        )}
                        label={({ color }) => <Text style={{ color }}>{route.name}</Text>}
                        focused={state.routes.findIndex((e) => e.name === route.name) === state.index}
                        activeTintColor={Colors.Primary}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.name)}
                        pressColor={Colors.StatusbarColor}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Comment: Here is how I achieved solution to my problem.Using the above way we can able to set activeTint color and backgroundColor to drawer Item

Answer (score 0):

```
in your <Drawer.Navigator/> There is a property named option which takes an 
object and in that object you can find the drawerActiveTintColor Property. That 
can be used to set the activeTintColor and it will change the background color 
 as well.


<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} 
         options={{ drawerActiveTintColor: 'red' }}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: This way its gives activetintColor and background but if you clearly observe my code I'm setting all my drawerItems inside drawerContent of DrawerNavigator where I'm not able to see changes in activeTintColor and background etc on drawerItem eventhough I set activeTintColor on Navigator options or on drawerItem it gives no change in activeListItem.

Comment: You need to also specify which item is actually active by specifying the "focused" prop on `DrawerItem` https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/56984a45a3c6e15994d3c747e3eb0371427c8e50/packages/drawer/src/views/DrawerItemList.tsx#L61

Comment: @satya164, When I use focused props on DrawerItem It shows true for every drawerItem even its not the active one I selected.So, All the Drawer Items getting same  active  color applied.

Comment: You're not supposed to pass `focused={true}` to everything. Pass `true` to the item that's actually focused, it's not going to know what's focused without doing anything.